# In Android, display Google Places JSON data in a list?

Tags: android, json

In the below code, I can display the first returned JSON place name result from my Google Places URL. Rather than just the first item, I'd like to display the whole returned list of place names. What would be the easiest way of doing this? Can you point me to a tutorial, or give sample code?

```
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(bcURL.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity(); 
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e); 
        json = new JSONObject(data); 
        JSONArray timeline = json.getJSONArray("results"); 
        JSONObject lastport = timeline.getJSONObject(0); 
        return lastport;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(NewGPS3.this, "oops", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
```

The line `JSONObject lastport = timeline.getJSONObject(0);` shows the first name. I'd like to show a list rather than just the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use a JSONArray object in order to get at the array.  It should go something like this:

```
JSONObject entireObject = new JSONObject("your JSON string here");
JSONObject mainObject = entireObject.getJSONObject("photos"); // main object in entire object
JSONArray arrayObject = mainObject.getJSONArray("photo"); // array object in the main object
```

You can then iterate through this array just like any other:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayObject.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject photoData = arrayObject.getJSONObject(i);
    String yourString = photoData.getString("id");
}
```

I got some of this out of Pro Android Media.  There is a really good JSON api call example in this book.  You can probably get the source code for free, too.

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Android-Media-Developing-Smartphones/dp/1430232676/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343062690&sr=8-1&keywords=android+media](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232676)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < timeline.size(); i++){
JSONObject lastport = timeline.getJSONObject(i); 
//Save the item to a ArrayList and use that list for your ListAdapter.
googlePlaces.add(lastPort);
}
```